# I've been trying to change the background color of the home and hard ware button in react native expo application

Tags: react-native, frontend, expo, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-development

I wish to change the background color of the home and hardware back button background in my expo react native application  ..

I tried using the react-native-background-color , and other but they required react-native linking which was not possible with react native expo from what I encountered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.